# How to compile C++ using Visual Stuido 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compilation, scada

I'm begening on TANGO Scada systems, and I'm working with devices, class and servers.

I'm asking for help because I download a Device Server for my application, but it's in C++, and I don't know how to compile it unsing Microsft Visual Studio 2015.

I need compilation because I can't use this Device Class in TANGO, but I'll pass on this.

If you want to take a look to the device class, i'll send you the link to download the file : [Link](http://sourceforge.net/p/tango-ds/code/HEAD/tree/DeviceClasses/MeasureInstruments/Lecroy/AcquireWaveformLecroy/)

I think I have to compile the **trunk\src** folder, but I'm not even sure.

Can someone help me ? Thanks !

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

You should run “nmake -f Makefile.VC” in command line from trunk/src directory to compile this sources with MS Visual C/C++ compiler.

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying. I tried this, and I got error : "nmake is not recognized as an internal or external command [...]"

Comment: You probably need to check your PATH environment variable and see if it contains the directory containing nmake.exe.  For Visual Studio 2015 community edition this should be:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin"

Comment: You can also click start -> All programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 -> Visual studio tools -> VS2015 x86 native tools command .

Comment: OK thanks, it works. Step by step. A new error occurs : "Makefile.VC(20) : fatal error U1052 : file '\env\tango.opt' not found". Any ideas ?

Comment: Just create in "src" direcrory "env" and put them empty file named "tango.opt"

Comment: Didn't work, same error. I created a directory "env", and i put inside an empty texte file named "tango.opt" and nothing changed...

Comment: It is possible that the "env" directory should not be inside the "src" directory, but one level higher or completely in the root directory of the disk. It is important that nmake.exe finds the desired file ("tango.opt") where it expects it.